# Ordering an array of numbers in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, generics

I am trying to use generic programming in Haskell and need to sort an array of numbers but for some reason when I run the code, I receive an error stating "No instance for (Fractional Nums) In the expression: 645.41...." Every time I look at my code, I think it makes sense, but I'm not sure why it does not work...

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
    
    
data Nums = Nums {numbers::Double} deriving(Ord, Eq, Show)
sortNums :: [Nums] -> [Nums]
sortNums = sortBy(comparing numbers)
arr =  [645.41, 37.59, 76.41, 5.31, 1.11, 1.10, 23.46, 635.47, 467.83, 62.25]
main:: IO ()

     main = 
          do
               print(sortNums arr)
```

I apologize if this code looks messy or does not make sense, I am new to Haskell....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason that's not obvious from the question, you should probably just delete `Nums` entirely.

```
import Data.List (sort)

arr :: [Double]
arr = [645.41, 37.59, 76.41, 5.31, 1.11, 1.10, 23.46, 635.47, 467.83, 62.25]

main :: IO ()
main = print (sort arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `arr` is an array of `Double`s, but you are calling `sortNums` on it, which requires an array of `Nums`. While these are effectively "the same" type, Haskell doesn't do any automatic conversions for you. If you replace `print(sortNums arr)` with `print (sortNums (map Nums arr))` - to ensure the list you're sorting has each member a `Nums` value - then this works as intended.

(The error message you received here is unfortunately rather confusing and unhelpful, but derives from the fact that literal floating-point values like `645.41` can represent a value of any type that's an instance of the `Fractional` typeclass. GHC sees you're trying to apply `sortNums` to the list, and that this needs a list of `Nums`, so it tries to make the values in the list of type `Nums` - which it can do, but only if there is a `Fractional` instance, which is why you get that specific error message. Don't worry too much about this - I'm just trying to explain why you get this particular error rather than one which would be more helpful like "couldn't match type `[Double]` with expected type `[Nums]`")

Answer (score 0):

To let the literals `1` or `3.1415` work for your type, you need them to be instances of `Num` and `Fractional` respectively:

```hs
>> :type 1
1 :: Num p => p
>> :type 3.1415
3.1415 :: Fractional p => p
```

This means you can instantiate `1` as `Int` and `Double`, but you can't instantiate it as your `Nums`.

```hs
>> 1 :: Int
1
>> 1 :: Double
1.0
>> 1 :: Nums

<interactive>:36:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num Nums) arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the expression: 1 :: Nums
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 1 :: Nums
```

Similarly you can instantiate `3.1415` as `Double` but not as `Int` or `Nums` because there is no `Fractional Int` instance and there is no `Fractional Nums` instance.

```hs
>> 1.0 :: Int

<interactive>:37:1-3: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal ‘1.0’
    • In the expression: 1.0 :: Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 1.0 :: Int
>> 1.0 :: Double
1.0
>> 1.0 :: Nums

<interactive>:39:1-3: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Nums) arising from the literal ‘1.0’
    • In the expression: 1.0 :: Nums
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 1.0 :: Nums
```

However it is possible to derive `Num`, `Fractional` instances for your `Nums`.

1. Make it a `newtype` instead of a `data` type. This makes it representationally equal to a `Double` at runtime.
2. This means you can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` (the `newtype` deriving strategy) to derive `Num` and `Fractional` for your `Nums` type (in fact any instance that `Double` has).
3. You can also use [`sortOn cmp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) = `sortBy (comparing cmp)`.

```
{-# Language DerivingStrategies         #-}
{-# Language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications           #-}

import Data.List (sortOn)

newtype Nums = Nums { numbers :: Double }
  deriving
  stock (Eq, Ord, Show)

  deriving
  newtype (Num, Fractional, Floating, Enum, Real, RealFloat, RealFrac)

sortNums :: [Nums] -> [Nums]
sortNums = sortOn numbers

arr :: Fractional a => [a]
arr = [645.41, 37.59, 76.41, 5.31, 1.11, 1.10, 23.46, 635.47, 467.83, 62.25]

-- >> main
-- [Nums {numbers = 1.1},Nums {numbers = 1.11},Nums {numbers = 5.31},Nums {numbers = 23.46},Nums {numbers = 37.59},Nums {numbers = 62.25},Nums {numbers = 76.41},Nums {numbers = 467.83},Nums {numbers = 635.47},Nums {numbers = 645.41}]
main :: IO ()
main = print (sortNums arr)
```

In actuality we are instantiating `arr :: [Nums]` which is only possible because we newtype derived `Fractional` for `Nums`:

```hs
>> :set -XTypeApplications
>>
>> arr @Float
[645.41,37.59,76.41,5.31,1.11,1.1,23.46,635.47,467.83,62.25]
>> arr @Double
[645.41,37.59,76.41,5.31,1.11,1.1,23.46,635.47,467.83,62.25]
>> arr @Double
[Nums {numbers = 645.41},Nums {numbers = 37.59},Nums {numbers = 76.41},Nums {numbers = 5.31},Nums {numbers = 1.11},Nums {numbers = 1.1},Nums {numbers = 23.46},Nums {numbers = 635.47},Nums {numbers = 467.83},Nums {numbers = 62.25}]
```